# GCloud compute instance halting but not stopping

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-compute

I want to run a gcloud compute instance only for the duration of my startup script. My startup script calls a nodejs script which spawns `sudo halt` or `shutdown -h 0`. Observing the serial port the system comes to a halt but remains in the RUNNING state, never going into STOPPING or TERMINATED:

```
         Starting Halt...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors,…sing dmeventd or progress polling.
         Stopping LVM2 metadata daemon...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped LVM2 metadata daemon.
[   34.560467] reboot: System halted
```

How is it possible that the system can halt completely but the instance doesn't register as such?

Comment: Have you tried `poweroff` rather than `halt`? https://serverfault.com/questions/191537/shutdown-what-is-difference-between-power-off-and-halt

Answer (score 1):

As @DazWilkin said in the comments, you can use `poweroff` to stop a VM instance in Compute Engine. Alternatively, per the official [Compute Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#stopping_an_instance_through_the_os) you can also run `sudo shutdown -h now` or `sudo poweroff` which will both accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there a difference between `sudo shutdown -h 0` and `sudo shutdown -h now`? I've been using '0' as I described in my question and that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not seeing an error though. The system actually comes to a halt as you can see in the logs when I run `sudo shutdown -h 0`. If I do it from within SSH it properly halts AND terminates the system (guestTerminate in stackdriver logs). If I run the command from within my startup script it only halts.

Comment: Apologies I was running tests in a Debian distribution and it would throw errors when running `sudo shutdown -h 0`. I am now testing it in Ubuntu and as you said, it works fine within SSH. I'm trying to reproduce the same issue you are having but meanwhile, could you confirm if the script is run as root?

Comment: Startup scripts always run as the root user by default. The system actually comes to a halt. The instance doesn't

Comment: I was able to reproduce this behavior. It seemed erratic that `shutdown -h now` will safely stop the instance regardless of any current running `node` processes but `shutdown -h +0` will not. As if it didn't seemed erratic enough, `shutdown -h +1` safely stops the instance after a minute of countdown. In any case, I would suggest using `shutdown -h now` since it has been proven to work against `shutdown -h +0`. `shutdown` should tell `init` to change the runlevel to 0 after the delay but I'm not sure if this is the case when the delay is 0.

Comment: Furthermore, on a `systemd` operating system, ( you can see if the Linux distribution you are using is systemd by running `ps aux` and checking if PID 1 is systemd), runlevels (`shutdown` would usually tell `init` to change the runlevel to 0 for a proper halt) are apparently [obsolete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195898/what-is-the-difference-between-these-commands-for-bringing-down-a-linux-server/196014#196014) and the `shutdown` command is handled by `systemctl`.